# lifetimes plot upside down

Tags: plot, survival-analysis, lifelines

I am learning survival analysis using the [lifelines library](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/lifelines). I am using the [leukemia dataset](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifelines.datasets.html). I was trying to plot the lifetimes plot. However, I am getting a plot which is upside down (i.e., flipped vertically).

I am using this [notebook](https://github.com/chrisluedtke/data-science-journal/blob/master/07-Advanced-Regression/02_Survival_Analysis.ipynb) as a reference. This is my code:

```
import lifelines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lifelines.datasets import load_leukemia
leukemia = load_leukemia()
durations = leukemia.t.values
events = leukemia.status.values
ax = lifelines.plotting.plot_lifetimes(durations=durations, event_observed=events)
ax.set_xlim(0, 40)
ax.set_xlabel("Time in Months")
plt.plot()
```

This is the plot that I am getting

[image]

This is the plot that I want to generate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure which one of the plots is correct, but the `lifelines` API was updated on 21 Mar 2019 (v. 0.20.2). As per the [changelog](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog.html?highlight=plot_lifetimes#api-changes-16):

> plot_lifetimes no longer reverses the order when plotting.

The github notebook is dated 11 Mar 2019, so I assume it was using the old API that would have resulted in the plot as depicted therein. However, all future versions of `lifelines` would result in the plot that you are getting.

So basically if you uninstall your current `lifelines` package and `pip install lifelines==0.24.13` (v. 0.24.13 is the latest `lifelines` version) you will get the plot that you are getting.

Cameron Davidson (`lifelines` author) might be able to shed some more light on it - may be the Leukemia dataset needs to be updated following the API change!